# Change menu based on user selection on Homepage

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I display/change a menu which is on _Layout page (also which is only visible after authentication)
based on what path has user selected on the home page?

On the home page user has three paths (Admin, Instructor, Student), I wanted to change the menu based on user selection, if someone selects Admin I show then different menu etc

The menu should not change until user goes back to home page and changes his selection. (Note: in my code I got lot of redirects)

Comment: Do the users have to login to browse the site? If so just check `Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "admin")` and display proper menu.

Comment: Yes. But menu selection is not based on login. Once they login user select a button on homepage which should change the menu.

Comment: Do those paths have their own controller? Is there an AdminController, an InstructorController e.t.c.?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I usually do in similar scenarios

1- I let the flag that will indicate how I should behave later be saved somehow (ex: session, HiddenField).

2- Building the menu is the responsibility of a partialview controlled by an action decorated with the following attribute: `[ChildActionOnly]`

3- Based on the saved flag, I pass the saved value to the child action and let it decide how to construct the menu elements

4- Accordingly, a `PartialView` should serve as a menu container, which should receive the menu items and render the final HTML for your users.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably check some value from the `RouteData`.

For instance if the menu depends on the controller (assuming each 'path' has its own controller), you could check the value of:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
```

in your `_Layout` page

Answer (score 0):

On the home page set the selected value in an HttpContext item as

```
HttpContext.Items["Menu"]="Admin";
```

or

```
HttpContext.Items["Menu"]="Student";
```

and so on..

And on the view just check the value of Menu item and show the menu accordingly

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.Items["Menu"]=="Admin")
{
      Show Admin Menus
}
else if(HttpContext.Items["Menu"]=="Student")
{
      Show Student menus
}
```

And so on.......

I hope it'll help you......